# With Tor, do i keep firefox installation

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

hi  thanks for the help..  i think i did look up question about having firefox but don't recall answer, for dealing with other security issues.

i notice recent hacks into firefox directory, affecting my pc so mentioning.
in regard, Question:  i only use tor, can i remove the firefox program?

originally:  hit with some coin miner virus.  symptom: run away task manager "CPU" & "Memory" severe-fast cycle from some value to a max value on many tasks, then repeats the memory cycle over-over, and tm tray icon flash wild 90% use?

now hit periodically:  pups? unwanted progs in firefox directory, and tor locking up, so the same question:  to remove the firefox program?

i'm sure i will figure it out, just think firefox may be affecting tor security.  (note:  i did to some back-forth unloading a tor version, could not work with vertical scroll bar moved from right side).  i have found a way to automate the window setting to be further off right side so not have a mouse click problem there..  but would suggest allow tor window (if position saveable), to allow off right side size as some apps intermittently allow.
thanks.

i will be able to figure this out.  just trying to pay back help got.  all i got - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

or

Navigate browser to URL "about:support" and click "Refresh" at top right.